# Copy data from Salesforce - PHP toolkit and curl

Tags: php, mysql, curl, salesforce

I need some help here. I am working on an export from Salesforce to MySQL database.

I may be choosing the wrong path here as I am a novice in both. What I have right now is a simple php query to our Salesforce. The query right now just echos the results to HTML. What I need to do is have this script connect to a MySQL database and add or update the records in the database.

Using the Salesforce PHP Toolkit my connection and query is this simple bit. (Appologies for the ugly inline html.

```
$query = "SELECT Id, FirstName, Random_Last_Initial__c, Created_Date__c,  Building_Zip_Code__c from Lead";
$queryResult = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$records = $queryResult->records;
foreach ($records as $record) {
  $sObject = new SObject($record);
  echo "<ul style='list-style:none;'>";
  echo "<li>Id = ".$sObject->Id;
  echo "</li><li>First Name = ".$sObject->fields->FirstName;
  echo "</li><li>Initial = ".$sObject->fields->Random_Last_Initial__c;
  echo "</li><li>Date Created = ".$sObject->fields->Created_Date__c;
  echo "</li><li>Zip = ".$sObject->fields->Building_Zip_Code__c;
  echo "</li></ul>";
}
```

All of that is fine, i just need to dump the results into the database.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the results to show up in the database?

Comment: notthing really to do with salesforce, you just need to to lean how to make a mysql INSERT query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work

```
$dbh  = New PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);

foreach ($records AS $record) 
{
    $sObject = New SObject($record);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO tablename SET sObjectId = :sid, firstName = :firstName, initial = :initial, createdDate = :created, zipCode = :zipcode");
    $stmt -> bindParam(':sid',          $sObject->Id);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':firstName',    $sObject->fields->FirstName);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':initial',      $sObject->fields->Random_Last_Initial__c);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':created',      $sObject->fields->Created_Date__c);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':zipcode',      $sObject->fields->Building_Zip_Code__c);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
```

Just fill out your database settings, table name, and column names as appropriate

Comment: I basically mirrored what you have here in the database itself but nothing is being stored in the table. It's not throwing any connection errors so I'm not sure what could be amiss.